# How to restore Xfce default panel colors?

Tags: themes, xfce

I would like to restore the default panel colors.

I had recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and then Xfce 4.12. Xfce brought a dark task bar, I think.

I experimented with the 3 themes from Ubuntu (Adwaita, Ambience, Radiance) but I would like to go back to the Xfce default. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that.

I tried to delete the contents of `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/` (which was empty), and `~/.config/xfce4/panel` didn't even exist. I also reinstalled Xfce, but Radiance is still showing up. Also, the icons appear to have changed.

The initial settings are not available as a theme. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: I have created a new user and seen that there is no theme selected (blank field) in the "Appearence" menu.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the xfce settings manager.  In your menu simply search for "Settings Manger".  NB: not Settings Editor.  Then go to Appearance, and select Greybird.  Go to the icons tab and select 'elementary Xfce dark.'  For fonts, your default should be Noto Sans, size 9.

If you want to reset everything in Xfce to default, instead of doing an apt-get remove, do an apt-get purge.  That will clean up your configuration files as well as uninstalling.  Then reinstall.

Edit:

Install the Greybird with the following:

```
cd ~
mkdir .icons
mkdir .themes
cd .icons
wget https://github.com/shimmerproject/elementary-xfce/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
mv elementary*/* .
cd ../.themes
wget https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Greybird theme in the Appearance menu (only Adwaita, Ambiance, Radiance, and High Contrast). Is this the case because I didn't install Xubuntu, but Xfce on top of Ubuntu? I am a bit new to this...

I did the purge-reboot-install as you recommended. But still Radiance. Interestingly, after the reboot I saw the 'old' dark menu bar shortly before Radiance got applied. Does that mean that my 'old' appearance is Ubuntu and not Xfce? Then I should re-frame my question as "How to deselect any theme in Ubuntu?"

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing your hypothesis is correct.  Try installing `xubuntu-desktop` package instead.  Xubuntu is not just ubuntu+xfce; it's a whole set of packages which makes a comfortable desktop environment.

Comment: I actually installed xubuntu-desktop. I meant that I didn't install Xubuntu directly from CD/stick.

Comment: Okay, @pegnose, I added another possibility.